What can I do if I want to turn the second element in a sublist into a float, but not every list in the list has a second element? Python
Here is an example of a list of lists.
[["Amber", "7.3"], ["Molly", "14.5"], ["Lisa"]]

As you can see, there are two lists that have a second element. These elements are strings but need to be converted into floats. The problem boils down to the last element in the list. The last element isn't a list, but just a string and I want my program to just ignore it.
I've tried a few different things but keep coming back to the basic
for i in lst:
    for x in i:
        float(x[1])

But of course I get an error because ("lisa") doesn't have a x[1] for it to change. I still want Lisa to exist in my list, I just want the numbers specifically to become floats.
[["Amber", 7.3], ["Molly", 14.5], ["Lisa"]]

I tend to overthink things so if something doesn't make sense or this isn't something I can do within python please let me know.
I apologize, I made a few mistakes when writing out my example which made things extremely confusing.
This is for a school assignment so I was trying to get across what I needed while being as vague about my actual code as possible. The actual example above has nothing to do with said assignment. Someone asked below how the final item in the list is a different structure. I believe they may have been asking why, in my original code, there were both tuples and a string. This was because I'm stupid and forgot to double check my own work. In the code I meant to sent, all three elements in the list, are lists. The final one is different from the rest as my actual function has to do with reading a file composed of basic calculations but written in plain English. So each line of the file is essentially just doing basic math on a calculator, with the final list of one element representing an enter key.

float() returns a value, you need to assign the result somewhere.

You can use an if statement and the len() function to check if the list x has a second element, before trying to convert it to a float.

However, if you already know that every sublist except the last one has a second element, you can exclude the last sublist from the main for loop by using slicing.

Is the last element supposed to be a 1-tuple?  It is not.  It is just a string.

You seem to be confusing lists and tuples. The first two items are tuples, not lists.

How is the data being created that not all elements have the same structure?

I'm sorry, I'm still new to coding and made a mistake when making the post itself. I'll edit it to try and be more clear.

"But of course I get an error because ("lisa") doesn't have a x[1] for it to change" - No. It does have a x[1]: 'i'. You get an error because you can't turn this into a float. The error message clearly explains this. But you also get an error from the other sub-lists, because you have too many loops. x already refers to individual strings like "Amber", and not to lists like ["Amber", "7.3"]; so the indexing doesn't make any sense. On top of all of that, ("Lisa") is not a tuple.

But to address the actually apparently asked question: obviously, if you want to do something to the "second element", but there might not be a second element, then the approach is to find out whether there is a second element, and then only do the work in that case. In other words, the problem is knowing how many elements there are - in other words, checking the length. I have added duplicates to try to explain both this, and the issues I point out in the above comment.

But of course I get an error because ("lisa") doesn't have a x[1] for it to change Yes it does.  ("lisa") is NOT a tuple!  Putting parentheses around one thing does not make it a tuple -- single-element tuples have an odd syntax.  You'd have to use ("lisa",) to make it a one-element tuple.  Otherwise ("lisa") is just a string that has useless parentheses around it, so x[1] is the character "i".

Tuples are immutable, so you can't modify these in place. You need to construct new tuples containing the modified second element.
Use a conditional expression to avoid trying to access x[1] when there's only one element.
You also shouldn't have nested loops. Your inner loop is iterating over all the items in each tuple, but you only want to convert the second item.
new_lst = [(x[0], float(x[1])) 
            if (isinstance(x, tuple) and len(x) == 2) 
            else x 
           for x in lst]


Please read [answer] and Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?. Solving the overall described problem is clearly too unfocused for a Stack Overflow question, and not well enough defined, nor searchable.

You can test for length before the conversion or wrap the conversion in a try/except block to catch the error.
for i in lst:
    for x in i:
        if len(x) > 1:
            float(x[1])

or
for i in lst:
    for x in i:
        try:
            float(x[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass

How you use the converted value may make one way or the other the better choice.
